# Turn off projected lines in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

How do I turn off the lines that are projected onto the 3 axis planes of the plot when hovering over the data? I haven't been able to figure out which setting is used to switch these off.

[plot with projected lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urF0D.png)

```
library(plotly)

# data
x <- runif(50, 0, 1)
y <- runif(50, 0, 1)
z <- runif(50, 0, 1)

# hide grid
ax <- list(
  title = "",
  showgrid = FALSE
)

# produce 3d plot
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'mesh3d') %>% 
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ax, zaxis = ax))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348625/can-you-remove-the-hover-coordinate-lines-in-plotly-python-scatter3d):

```
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'mesh3d') %>% 
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(showspikes=FALSE), 
                      yaxis = list(showspikes=FALSE), 
                      zaxis = list(showspikes=FALSE)))
```

[image]